# Why don't work multiple tabs into one page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple tabs but not work, how I can resolve? I think problem are the id because more id create conflict...If I click on other tabs not display information into content. How can this problem be solved? is it possible to simplify the js so that it dynamically works? Can anyone help me find the problem and fix it?

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I made this into a runnable demo. When you click any of the buttons it changes the tab content...so it's not clear what the problem is. Also you seem to have repeated all of the HTML code identically 4 times, and I can't really think why you have done that. Please [edit] your post to clarify the question and the problem. See also [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: `Can anyone help me find the problem` can you describe the problem?  Do you get an error?  Is there some behavior that isn't what you expected?

Comment: ID attributes **must** be unique - when there are duplicates how is the browser/javascript supposed to know which of the dom elements is actually being referred to when you call getElementById?

Comment: yes i have insert this codice into the foreach and i have problem with id

Comment: Append some suffix then, like a loop counter value, so that you get IDs `London-0`, `London-1` etc. instead.

Comment: ok work but this create new problem:

tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

Comment: It's unclear what the new problem is, you didn't explain it (again). If you have new code and information for us please [edit] your question, do not put it into the comments. That way you can give a full explanation and also format it correctly to be readable.

Comment: But anyway the answer is already below, much neater than the way you were trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Without using ID attributes at all it is possible to accomplish what I think it is you are trying to do. If you replace the `id` attribute with a `data-id` attribute ( you can legitimately have duplicate dataset attributes ) you can use the `event` to begin a DOM traversal to find the tab that you wish to open. Below I used a helper function `getsibling` to work down the DOM tree  and try to identify a node based upon the `expr` parameter given - this expression uses the `data-id` from the button to identify the tab with the same `data-id` that is **after** the button in the DOM.

```js
const _cn = 'active';

const getsibling = (n, expr) => {
  do {
    if (Element.prototype.matches.call(n, expr)) return n;
    n = n.nextElementSibling;
  } while (n != null && n.nodeType == 1);
  return n;
};

const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabcontent');
const bttns = document.querySelectorAll('.tablinks');


/*
  bind delegated event listener to each of the button container elements
  and use the `event` to find the clicked button.
*/
document.querySelectorAll('div.tab').forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if( e.target != e.currentTarget && e.target.hasAttribute('data-id') ) {

      tabs.forEach(tab=>tab.style.display = 'none');
      bttns.forEach(bttn=>{ if( bttn != e.target ) bttn.classList.remove( _cn ) });
      e.target.classList.toggle( _cn );

      // now to find the NEXT element in the DOM that has the same data-id as the button...
      let tab = getsibling(e.target.parentNode, 'div[data-id="' + e.target.dataset.id + '"]');
          tab.style.display = !e.target.classList.contains( _cn ) ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}



.tabcontent:not(.tabcontent ~ .tabcontent) {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" data-id='London'>London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='Paris'>Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='Tokyo'>Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div data-id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>





<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='London'>London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='Paris'>Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='Tokyo'>Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div data-id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>








<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='London'>London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='Paris'>Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='Tokyo'>Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div data-id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>









<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='London'>London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='Paris'>Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id='Tokyo'>Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div data-id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok works, is possible to display all first tab into display block? now if i don't click not display

Comment: I think the last modification to the above css did what you ask